# How can I get all the hops in a path of unknown length with neo4j-python?

Tags: python, neo4j

```
MATCH (u:User {name: $user}), (target:Group {name: $group}), p=shortestPath((u)-[*]->(target)) RETURN p
```

When I run the above query in the Neo4j web UI, a fell graph of the resulting paths is displayed.

However, when I run the same query with the `neo4j-python` driver, only a `Path` objects with limited information are returned

```
<Path start=479557 end=404582 size=1>
```

How can I use Cypher and python to get complete path details, including all nodes and the relationships that connect them?

Comment: The Path object should have all the relationships, it is actually an iterable for Relationship, see here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/1.2/neo4j/v1/types.py#L248

Comment: Thanks! I'll submit a PR  to make the documentation clearer about that http://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/types.html#neo4j.v1.Path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on how you want to return data, but you can try something like this

```
MATCH (u:User {name: $user}), (target:Group {name: $group}),
p=shortestPath((u)-[*]->(target)) RETURN nodes(p),relationships(p)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Is there a way to return the relationships like a linked list, so I don't need to manually map back the relationships to the nodes to get something like this?

`n1 -[r1]->n2->n3-[r2]-n4`

Comment: Yes, you can just return the path itself.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the help everyone! For reference, here's my complete example that converts paths to human-readable strings for console or email output.

```
def find_paths_from_standard_user_to_domain_admins(standard_user, domain_admins_group):
    """Returns a list of paths that a standard user could take to get domain admin credentials"""
    results = []
    query = "MATCH (u:User {name:{user}}), (target:Group {name: {group}})," \
            "p=allShortestPaths((u)-[*]->(target)) RETURN p"
    with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            for record in tx.run(query, user=standard_user, group=domain_admins_group):
                relationships = record["p"].relationships
                nodes = record["p"].nodes
                path = ""
                for i in (range(len(relationships))):
                    path += "{0}-[{1}]->".format(nodes[i]["name"], relationships[i].type)
                path += nodes[-1]["name"]
                results.append(path)
    return results
```

This is a query for a graph generated by the [Bloodhound](https://github.com/BloodHoundAD/BloodHound) project, which builds graphs of Active Directory structures. It's extremely useful for domain admins, system architects, network defenders, and pentesters.

Answer (score 0):

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/4.0/api.html#path

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/4.0/api.html#relationship

```
from neo4j import (
    Path,
    Relationship,
)

...

result = session.run("MATCH (u:User {name: $user}), (target:Group {name: $group}), p=shortestPath((u)-[*]->(target)) RETURN p", user="example", name="example").single()

record = result.single()
session.close()

path = record["p"]

assert isinstance(path, Path)

for relationship in path:
   assert isinstance(relationship, Relationship)
```