# Missing return information when using Neo4j python driver

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j python driver to query my database, and with it, I'm trying to return the **complete paths** that exist from a single node:

```
MATCH path=(a)<-[*]-(b) WHERE ID(a) = 51 RETURN path, length(path) as len ORDER BY len
```

[image]

Image 1 - Result obtained when executing the query on the Neo4j web interface

When I use the python driver to execute the same query I get the following result

[image]

Image 2 - Same query using Neoj4 python driver (this are prints of the variable **rec['path']**, being rec the foreach var used to iterate result)

As you can see from the printed objects, it only returns the start and end node for each path, contrary to the web interface that shows every node in between.

Is there a way to get the result from the query using Neo4j python driver to also return the nodes in between, similar to the way that the web interface shows the query result in text mode?

Cumpz

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42458881/6692895) should solve your problem.

basic explanation :

The Path object should have all the relationships, it is actually an iterable for Relationship.